Using multiprocessing ('spawn') together with Polars raised `concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool`
I have a large number of big parquet files (1000 * 1G) on a big SDD, and I want to apply a somewhat complex function written in Polars (read the parquet, then many group_by, join, window, and aggregation operations...) to each parquet file and save the results separately.
I use multiprocessing ('spawn') together with Polars to speed up (the speedup is significanly):

with ProcessPoolExecutor(10, mp_context=multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")) as executor:
    futures = {}
    for file in files:
        futures[
            executor.submit(func, file=file)
        ] = date
    for future in tqdm(as_completed(futures), total=len(futures)):
        future.result()  

But error is raised after a few parquet files are finished:
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

And spawn, fork, forkserver and a small number of workers (even max_workers=2) all give the same error.
The time of error raising is somewhat random, and indeed I can re-run the program several times to get the full results.
It is realy hard to give a mininal example, using smaller parquet file or simpler Polars procedures or parquet files on HDD does not raise any error.
Some posts said it may be due to limited memory or cpu cores, e.g.
https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6903#issuecomment-973657408
In my case, the memory used is just 10% of total memory, but the load average is above twice the number of cpu cores. So I add os.environ['POLARS_MAX_THREADS'] = str(int(os.cpu_count() / 2)) just above the with code blocks (i.e., the polars has already been imported) or run with env POLARS_MAX_THREADS=half the cpu cores in CLI,  no exception occurred but performance degraded.
I want to know the cause of the error and whether there are more pragmatic ways to avoid such error.

Have you ever figured out what the issue was here?
